# Comparing two NSNumber objects

Tags: ios, comparison, nsnumber

I used this code to compare two NSNumber objects, but it never passed the if condition.

```
listItems = [appDelegate.productStatus componentsSeparatedByString:@","];


for (int i=0;i<[appDelegate.productArray count]; i++)
{

    for (int j=0; j<[listItems count]; j++) 
    {
        number=[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[listItems objectAtIndex:j] intValue]];
        NSLog(@"number %@",number);
        productObject=[appDelegate.productArray objectAtIndex:i];           
        NSLog(@"%@,%@",productObject.pid,number);
        if (productObject.pid == number) 
        {
            NSLog(@"BUY it!!!");
            [purchasArray addObject:productObject];
        }

    }
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Try with isEqual instant of ==.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

My sugestion is to compare it as

```
if([productObject.pid intValue] == [number intValue])
{
 NSLog(@"BUY it!!!");
        [purchasArray addObject:productObject];
}
```

cheers.

I'd avoid object comparison

Comment: right, but [number intValue] ain't necessary, because number is built from a int few lines above. so it could be if([productObject.pid intValue] == [[listItems objectAtIndex:j] intValue])

Answer (score 30):

Change following code..

```
if ([productObject.pid isEqualToNumber number]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"BUY it!!!");
        [purchasArray addObject:productObject];
    }
```

Hope, this will help you..

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 13):

Try **compare** method instead of '=='.

```
if([1stNum compare:secNum] == NSOrderedSame) 
  {
      // do something
  }
```

Tell me if it helps now!

Comment: it come error: -[NSCFString isEqualToNumber:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x753e5e0'

Answer (score 2):

Use like this I thing this will helpful for you

```
NSNumber *n=[[NSNumber alloc]init];
if([n isEqualToNumber:somenumber])
 {
 }
```

Comment: it shown this erro   -[NSCFString isEqualToNumber:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x753e5e0'

Comment: Because I dont know what is your productObject.pid.for comparing both should be number so check that.